# Generic code to align non-constant-width text on QLabel

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5, c++14

I want to align text as follow on a QLabel:

```
name         : value
more         : other value
longer name  : value
```

It is easily done as follow

```
QString str;
str += "name\t\t: value\n";
str += "more\t\t: other value\n"
str += "longer name\t: value"
```

**The question is**, if I do not know the string pairs beforehand, is there a way in Qt to determine how many `\t`-chars must each string get so that they align on the `:` (if tabs are the only option)?

I can't use QString::arg() since the text is displayed on a GUI using non-constant-width-text. The issue here is that if I count the number of chars and set the *fieldWidth* the `:` does not align since the width of each char is not the same (changing the font is not an option)

I have tried some logic to count and then 'guess' the number of tabs to insert, which works in general but there might be some corner cases where it might not work.

I can also not make use of any other widgets since the code has only access to the one `QLabel*` that it must update.

Comment: you can use `setw` instead of tabs (would need to pipe it into a stringstream and then extracting the string from the stream)

Comment: Another idea is use three labels per string; first label you make it right align, second align is center align and third label is left aligned. And then group them together or if you want to keep your original style make the first label left align

Comment: I may have misunderstood but... the real problem here is actually the fact that the font being used is (or might be) proportionally spaced?  If it weren't for that then a simple character count would suffice.  Sorry if I'm stating the obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think an alignment using a "white space" characters may fail if a font used is not monospace.

You should use [QGridLayout](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html) or, if you really need to archive this using only one `QLable`, you may align text using html tags (`table`, `tr`, `td`).

Comment: Thanks, `html` text was the solution I was looking for. 
Not clear in the question, but I only had the `QLabel*` at the point where I could set the text, thus any other options that required more widgets were not viable.

Comment: @TheBadger As an aside: when you have a pointer to a widget, you can get a pointer to its parent and to the parent's layout, and from there is a short road to adding arbitrary widgets around yours. So having "just" a `QLabel*` is not a limitation. This of course has nothing to do with the sensible approach here - using html.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this problem in the way I describe below. For the sake of simplicity I just print out the output in the requested format, but you can modify the function on your own to set the label's text:

```
// Prints out the content as an aligned table
static void print(const QList<QPair<QString, QString>> &input)
{
  // Calculate the longest name.
  int longestName = 0;
  for (const auto &i : input) {
    longestName = std::max(longestName, i.first.length());
  }

  // Print out the content.
  for (const auto &i : input) {
    const auto &name = i.first;
    qDebug() << QString("%1%2 : %3")
                        .arg(name)
                        .arg(QString(longestName - name.length(), ' '))
                        .arg(i.second);
  }
}
```

I.e. at the beginning I calculate the length of the longest name and use that information for alignment.

And here is the usage example:

```
QList<QPair<QString, QString>> input =
{
  { "name", "value" },
  { "more", "other value" },
  { "longer name", "other value" },
};

print(input);
```

Comment: Your solution does not work with non-monospace fonts.

Comment: Unfortunately as @Andrii pointed out, this works if you print out the text or display in monospace fonts, but not on a widget with a non-monospace font, like Arial.

Comment: @TheBadger, that means you cannot solve your problem by aligning your string using spaces.

Comment: @vahancho Thus the question, tabs seemed to work, but getting it generic was the problem. The html table is easy and works correct. This is a good example why one should not as XY questions...